# How to use smack library to build a client application so that i receive incoming messages as they keep coming?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am using this code where i use the smack library to connect to the Google server.But the issue is that i do not know how to keep the code running so that i can keep sending and receiving messages.Please be so kind as to help me with this.I am copy pasting the code :

```
// connect to gtalk server
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
connection.connect();

// login with username and password
connection.login("camel.test.1", "secret");

// set presence status info
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
connection.sendPacket(presence);

// send a message to somebody
Message msg = new Message("xxx.xxx@gmail.com", Message.Type.chat);
msg.setBody("hello");
connection.sendPacket(msg);

connection.disconnect();
```

Please do note that sending message works fine with this code.Let me know of the modifications i need to do in the same code so that i can use it for both sending and receiving messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't let your application terminate.
- Don't disconnect the connection.
- Register a [PacketListener](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/PacketListener.html) to listen for incoming messages.